# Can I create a file upload (with custom forms) Phonegap app for iPad that works offline

Tags: javascript, ios, ruby-on-rails, html, cordova

We've created a Rails app that allows users to upload PDFs or fill in our custom forms and submit. These users need to use the app without wifi and I'm wondering if there's a way to incorporate this into an iPad phonegap app?

Comment: no, ipad has no files to upload...

Comment: I don't see how you can do this in iOS.  Perhaps if it had support for IndexedDB, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To create a phonegap app, you can create a SPA [single-page-application](/questions/tagged/single-page-application) using html, css, and js.  Think single index.html page without any backend code that shows your form.  When offline, you can save the form data to [local-storage](/questions/tagged/local-storage).  When online, you can send the form data with AJAX to your web service.  RESTfull services on the server handle these very well.

Comment: It sounds like the OP was looking for a way to also persist files, such as PDFs, while offline.  LocalStorage won't work well for this.

Comment: I read:  "users to upload PDFs or fill in our custom forms".  My answer address only the fill in our custom forms.  I hope this answers a part of his question.

Comment: Yes, seems like it does address that part.